# document is not defined with jshint

Tags: jshint

In this code:

```
$scope.others=[some data...]
$scope.tab=[];
$scope.smt = function(x){
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.others; i++){
            var el = angular.element(document.querySelector('#'+x));
            if (el.hasClass("myClass")){
                sel.push($scope.tab[i]);
            }
        }
}
```

JSHint complains about:

> 'document' is not defined

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `"browser" : true` to your jshint configuration or `/* jshint browser: true */` at the top of your file to let jshint know that your environment is a browser. See [documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#browser)